# How to Augment the Training Set using the tf.keras.utils.Sequence API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

TensorFlow documentation have the following example that can illustrate how to create a batch generator to feed a training set in batches to a model when the training set is too large to fit in memory:

```py
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math

# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class CIFAR10Sequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

My intention is to further increase the diversity of the training set by rotating each image 3x by 90º. In each Epoch of the training process, the model would first be fed with the "0º training set" and next with the 90º, 180º and 270º rotating sets, respectively.

How can I modify the previous piece of code to perform this operation inside the `CIFAR10Sequence()` data generator?

Please don't use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` so that the answer does not lose its generality for another type of similar problems that are of a different nature.

NB: The idea would be to create the new data "in real time" as the model is fed instead of creating (in advance) and storing on disk a new and augmented training set bigger than the original one to be used later (also in batches) during the training process of the model.

Thx in advance

Comment: Are your images stored in directory with label names as directory names?

Comment: Yes, my images are stored in directory with label names as directory names.

Comment: I'm not sure what your final comment in the question means. Can you elaborate a little on why `ImageDataGenerator()` isn't suitable for your case?

Comment: I think `ImageDataGenerator()` is probably suitable for this particular case. However, I would like to know how to do it by modifying the previous code to learn how to do a similar procedure with data of a different nature such as cubic volumes and more complex types of rotations.

Comment: Dealing with big data and scarce computing resources is a problem faced by many data scientists around the world. And it is in this context that "batch generators" can make all the difference. They can help data scientists to deal with data sets that are too large to fit memory as well as can still be used for data augmentation (and consequently increasing the accuracy of models) without requiring more memory or disk space. It's definitely an interesting topic.

Comment: The aim of the proposed problem was to generate some discussion around this topic and it is just an example. If anyone have a solution for a similar problem and are interested in showing it, please don't hesitate and publish it here.

Comment: @mujjiga thanks for your answer! You came up with a more sophisticated solution for a more sophisticated problem than the one I presented. When I wrote, "In each Epoch of the training process, the model would first be fed with the "0º training set" and next with the 90º, 180º and 270º rotating sets, respectively.", what I wish I had said and the output I expected to see was something like this:

Epoch 1/10 Rotating Angle: 0 Rotating Angle: 90 Rotating Angle: 180 Rotating Angle: 270 (...) Epoch 10/10 Rotating Angle: 0 Rotating Angle: 90 Rotating Angle: 180 Rotating Angle: 270

Comment: @mujjiga athough it is not the exact solution to the problem I presented, your solution is great! I definitely marked it as useful!!! even though my vote do not change the publicly displayed post score because my reputation in stackoverflow is under than 15. See you soon to close my question. Cheers

Comment: mujjiga presented a solution that rotates the images at the beginning of the next epoch. However, the solution I am looking for involves rotating the images within each epoch such that the output is as follows:

``
Epoch 1/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 270

(...)

Epoch 10/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 270
``

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom `Callback` and hook into `on_epoch_end`. After each epoch end change the angle of the data iterator object.

#### Sample  (documented inline)

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize, rotate
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.utils import Sequence 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense

# Model architecture  (dummy)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(15, 15, 4)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Data iterator 
class CIFAR10Sequence(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, filenames, labels, batch_size):
        self.filenames, self.labels = filenames, labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.angles = [0,90,180,270]
        self.current_angle_idx = 0

    # Method to loop throught the available angles
    def change_angle(self):
      self.current_angle_idx += 1
      if self.current_angle_idx >= len(self.angles):
        self.current_angle_idx = 0
  
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.filenames) / float(self.batch_size)))

    # read, resize and rotate the image and return a batch of images
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        angle = self.angles[self.current_angle_idx]
        print (f"Rotating Angle: {angle}")

        batch_x = self.filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        return np.array([
            rotate(resize(imread(filename), (15, 15)), angle)
               for filename in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)

# Custom call back to hook into on epoch end
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, sequence):
      self.sequence = sequence

    # after end of each epoch change the rotation for next epoch
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
      self.sequence.change_angle()               


# Create data reader
sequence = CIFAR10Sequence(["f1.PNG"]*10, [0, 1]*5, 8)
# fit the model and hook in the custom call back
model.fit(sequence, epochs=10, callbacks=[CustomCallback(sequence)])
```

Output:

```
Rotating Angle: 0
Epoch 1/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 0
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 755ms/step - loss: 1.0153 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 90
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 190ms/step - loss: 0.6975 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 180
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 772ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/10
Rotating Angle: 270
Rotating Angle: 270
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 197ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 0
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 189ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 6/10
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 90
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 757ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 7/10
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 180
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 757ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 8/10
Rotating Angle: 270
Rotating Angle: 270
2/2 [==============================] - 2s 761ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 9/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 0
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 744ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 10/10
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 90
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 192ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5000
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fcbdf8bcdd8>
```

Comment: But how can I create a function that runs on the end of an epoch that changes the angle value and continues training on the same epoch (without changing to the next epoch)?

Comment: Even though it was not the solution that I was looking for, I have to recognize that your solution also solves the problem that I proposed. So, I accepted your answer. Thank you very much!